# Possible to Modify QGIS WFS-T Request?

Tags: qgis, geoserver

When trying to edit a wfs-t dataset served through GeoServer (2.5.2) - I edit my data and save, however everytime I get an empty response. Using Fiddler2 I modify the request and the transaction goes through fine.

```
Bad part of request
 xsi:schemaLocation="workspaceURI http://webaddress/geoserver/workspace/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;TYPENAME=workspace:prop_bound&amp;SRSNAME=EPSG:3308&amp;username=***&amp;password=***" 

Modification of request
xsi:schemaLocation="http://webaddress/geoserver/workspace/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;TYPENAME=workspace:prop_bound&amp;SRSNAME=EPSG:3308&amp;username=***&amp;password=***"
```

Removing the workspace uri from in front of the schema location address is solving the problem, however is there a way I can modify the request that is made through QGIS or is this a GeoServer issue? I have had this issue using QGIS 2.4,2.6 and 2.8

Comment: What schemaLocation is advertized in the DescribeFeatureType? Request is like `http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=describefeaturetype&typename=topp:states`

Answer (score 2):

OK fixed - I had to change the workspace URI to http://www.opengis.net/wfs (I was under the assumption that it was supposed to be unique identifier being a combination of your server address/workspace?)

Secondly I had to set the SRS handling to 'Keep native'

After those two changes the WFT-T successfully updates - 9 months trying to figure out this!!!!

Answer (score 1):

How about you change it in your WFS connection?

Set that up in QGIS, I think it will work if you just go

```
http://webaddress/geoserver/wfs?
```

Comment: That doesn't change the xsi:schemaLocation value - it still shows up as having the workspace in front.